# Make "python" run python3 at the prompt

Tags: python, shell, terminal, symlink

I have two python installations..

`python` --> `/Users/fraz/anaconda/bin/python` (python2.7)

`python3.7` --> `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

Now.. I want reassign the commands. Such that
`python` points to `python3.7` --> `/usr/local/bin/python3.7`

and `python2` points to `python2.7` `/Users/fraz/anaconda/bin/python`

How  do i do this reassignment?

Comment: What environment are you using?  Linux?  Windows?

Comment: @wallyk oops.. mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17536/how-do-i-create-a-permanent-bash-alias), modify your `~/.bashrc`, add a new line:

```
alias python=python3.7
```

save and exit
then open terminal, type

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

in my machine, typing `python2` will open python 2.x by default. but if needed, you can add a new alias

```
alias python2=python2.7
```

Comment: This is specific to Bash, and to interactive sessions. A more portable solution which works for any shell is to add `$HOME/bin` (or whatever you want to call it) to the very front of your `PATH`, and populate it with symlinks to your preferred version whenever you want to override the system-wide default. If you have third-party scripts you rely on, they will generally expect `python` to run Python 2, though; so perhaps a better and more robust solution is to just learn to type `python3` when that's what you mean.

Comment: @tripleee would you mind posting a new answer so I can upvote it ? btw I agree with you, people should get used to typing `python3` (or `python2`).

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you can use softlink

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python /usr/local/bin/python3.7
```