# Python or Python3. What is the difference?

Tags: python

What is the difference between the following commands:

```
python setup.py
```

and

```
python3 setup.py
```

- What if I only have python3.6 installed? `python` and `python3` would do the same thing?
- Does it make difference only when I have different versions of python installed? If so, which version will be used with `python setup.py`?

Comment: Maybe `python` is Python 2. Maybe it's Python 3. Maybe it's a different version of Python 3. Maybe it's nothing. Depends how your system is set up. Use `python -V` to check.

Comment: Because we had python2 before and that has reached end of life. So on newer systems without python2, python and python3 both use python3. If you have multiple python versions the latest one will be used. But even then, you can use python virtual environment to "lock" your dependencies and python version (pipdeptree > req.txt, , pip - r req.txt )

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57368515/make-python-run-python3-at-the-prompt (not sure if that can be considered a duplicate)

Answer (score 23):

There is no single correct answer here, but we can offer some common observations.

- Some Linux distributions decided during the transition from Python 2 to Python 3 that `python` should always refer to Python 2, and the command to run Python 3 would be `python3` with a 3 at the end. Now that Python 2 is becoming obsolete, this is being relaxed in some distros (i.e. now that they no longer ship Python 2 at all, the `python` command can be allowed to point to Python 3, too), but this is going to continue to exist in some form for some time.

  - See [PEP 394](https://peps.python.org/pep-0394/)
- Debian-based Linux distros have a mechanism called [`update-alternatives`](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianAlternatives) which lets you define which version of `python` exactly will be linked to the system-wide standard `/usr/bin/python`.  There is similarly a set of alternatives for `/usr/bin/python3`.
- If you have manually installed Python 3 somewhere, what works depends on where it was installed and whether that location is in your `PATH`.  A common arrangement is to have Python 3.14.159 somewhere like `/opt/python-3.14.159/bin/python3.14.159` and then rely on users who want to use this to create a symlink or alias to this binary so that they can simply call it `python` (or `python3`, or obviously also e.g. `shirley` if they prefer that)
- If you have an interactive alias, function, or personal shell script in your `PATH` with either of these names, obviously that overrides any system-wide setting, and could basically do anything at all, including but not limited to running a specific version of Python, ideally with all the command line arguments intact and correctly quoted (`/path/to/system-wide/default/python "$@"`) but obviously with no guarantees of any sort.
- On Windows, where many of these facilities don't exist, a common arrangement is for Python to be installed in `C:\python3.14.159\bin\Python.exe`; you then have to have `C:\python3.14.159\bin` in your `PATH` for the `python` command to work. The installer lets you install the package anywhere, but if you just go with the defaults, this is what you commonly end up with. Because of the cumbersomeness of Windows, the standard install also includes a command [`py`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) which works around some of the rigidity of the platform to let you flexibly indicate which Python version exactly to run. There is usually not a separate `python3` command, though users are of course free to create a `CMD` file with that name to run Python (or play a video of Rick Astley performing his biggest hit if they so prefer).
- If you have installed multiple versions of Python, the directory it was installed in needs to be in your `PATH`; if multiple directories which are on your `PATH` contain a `python` or `python3` binary or script, the one earlier in your `PATH` takes precedence. See also below.

  A related problem arises when you have a `PYTHONPATH` which overrides or complements Python's `sys.path`. Out of the box, this should point to wherever your Python packages were installed when you installed Python, but there are many ways to get this mixed up, especially if you are doing something to override the defaults of the Python version you are trying to use.

To help us help you debug questions about your installation, you will commonly need to tell us exactly what you installed where and how, and show us the value of your [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)).  If you have relevant functions, aliases, or personal shell scripts which shadow the system-wide default ones, show them too. On Unix-based platforms, the `type` and `command` commands can be used to show what will be executed (many guidances will tell you to use `which` or `whereis`, but [don't](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/85249/why-not-use-which-what-to-use-then); now we have to guess which non-standard command you are using, and where it is going to look). The Windows command `whereis` provides roughly the same functionality.

Python can be obtained from many places (downloaded and double-clicked an installer? Conda? Homebrew? Chocolatey? The native package manager of your OS? Configured how? Compiled from source? Using which options?) and what to expect can depend on where you got it from and how you installed and configured it. The more details you can provide, the better a question can you ask.

---

<sup>Don't call me Shirley, please.</sup>

Answer (score 6):

*NOTE: Answer provided with specific consideration for it now being 2023, and for Windows users*

#### Nowadays, python = python3

To answer your questions, given the example of...

```
> python  setup.py
> python3 setup.py
```

- What if I only have python3.6 installed? **These would/should run in the same version of python, e.g. 3.6**
- Do python and python3 do the same thing? **In 2023, they should yes**
- Does it make difference when different versions are installed? If so, which version will be used? **The other answers cover this in really good detail**

---

#### Some config may be required (and recommended)

- If you want your system to accept either `python setup.py` or `python3 setup.py` and run these commands on the whichever version of python you have installed then I would recommend creating a ***symbolic link*** from `python3 ==> python`
- If you don't know how to do that, copy the code below into notepad.exe, save it as 'python3-as-python.bat` (remember to select 'All files'), then right click and choose 'Run as Administrator'

```
python3-as-python.bat
---------------------

@ECHO OFF
:: Creates an alias for python3, any python3 [...] commands will be executed as if typed as python [...]
:: Checks default locations for single-user install and all-user install
:: Run as adminstrator if possible (required if python was installed for all users)

IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\Python3*" (
    PUSHD "%ProgramFiles%\Python3*"
    MKLINK python3.exe python.exe >nul
    IF EXIST python3.exe ECHO Python found in 'Program Files', alias created for python3 --^> python
)

IF EXIST "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python*" (
    PUSHD "%LocalAppData%\Programs\Python\Python*"
    MKLINK python3.exe python.exe >nul
    IF EXIST python3.exe ECHO Python found in user's 'AppData' folder, alias created for python3 --^> python
)

ECHO.
PAUSE
GOTO:EOF
```

---

#### Rationale

- Having just installed the latest version of python (3.11) from [python.org](https://python.org) myself, this was something I was also forced to try and work out as when I ran any commands like `python3 setup.py` I got an error saying python was not installed
- As of April 2023 (and possibly earlier), the official python installer only provides/creates `python.exe` and while it adds this to the `%PATH%` for ease-of-reference it does **NOT** create `python3.exe`, so any scripts or code with commands like `python3 setup.py` would need to be converted to `python setup.py`
- With genuine credit and respect to the previous answers provided, in my option the simplest answer is that nowadays `python == python3`. Given the nature of it being 2023 and python3 coming out in 2008, the number of instances where people explicitly need to run python scripts on a ***15-year old version***(!) should be extremely minimal
- NOTE: I am not trying to dismiss any of the advice or cautions given, but rather provide a simple, up-to-date answer that applies to most people.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it will make difference if you have different versions of python installed.

This depends on the entries in on the PATH environment variable. Suppose you have two python installations, 2.7 and 3.8, now you have installed 2.7 before 3.8, and both were added to PATH, so when you type `python`, 2.7 interpreter launches. If you have done vice versa, then 3.8 would launch. You can type `where python` to determine location.

Also one thing is that there is a launcher named `py`, just type `py -3.8` 3.8 interpreter will launch and same on `py -2.7`

Comment: For the longest time, `py` was specific to Windows, but a similar mechanism is now available for other systems as an option, too.