# No module named 'gsdmm'-topic modelling

Tags: python, installation

I have problems to work with GSDMM model of topic modelling dedicated for short text.
I followed this link to install it: https://towardsdatascience.com/gsdmm-topic-modeling-for-social-media-posts-and-reviews-8726489dc52f. but it didn't work. I also installed the model using the following command: pip install GPyM-TM (https://pypi.org/project/GPyM-TM/) but nothing works. I got the following error:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gsdmm'
any help?
thank you

Comment: I guess you failed to install `gsdmm` from the first post and `GPyM-TM` is a different package to that used by the first post with different classes (`GSDMM` instead of `gsdmm`) and won't be a drop in package. What happened when you ran `python setup.py install` for the `gsdmm` package? What was the output?

Comment: Sorry for being late to respond and thank you for your feedback. when I try to excute this command, this is the output: Command 'python' not found, did you mean:

  command 'python3' from deb python3
  command 'python' from deb python-is-python3

Comment: If you are using python3, then use that instead of python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801225/python-or-python3-what-is-the-difference)

Comment: I used python3 but though it didn't resolve the problem, it shows a message that i do not have write access to this directory. so, I used this instead: python3 setup.py install --user and the package is installed

Answer (score 0):

> python3 setup.py install --user

without the "--user", I have a message that says that I do not have write access to this directory and when I add the "--user", the package was installed and it works

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/short-text-topic-modelling-lda-vs-gsdmm-20f1db742e14) article about GSDMM helped me to resolve the issue.
need to install GSDMM using `pip install git+https://github.com/rwalk/gsdmm.git`