# Force PYSPARK to use python, not python3, when running PYTEST: "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2..."

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, pytest

For development we use `Pytest 7.4` (and Visual Studio Code). After struggling a little bit to find the proper compatibility of libraries with fresh installs, I found an error regarding `PySpark 3.5` needing `python3` instead of `python` (Python 3.11.3). In command line both `python` or `py` work, but not `python3` (not recognised by CMD as a command) even when `python` and `python3` are the same (and I do not have `python2`).

To solve this my solution was, as pointed by the error, to edit the `context.py` of PySpark file from the site-packages of Python (`...\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py`) by deleting the `3` at line 320 from the string

`self.pythonExec = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_PYTHON", "python")`

Another workaround was to force in the test script to use the system environment, like in [PYCHARM Error-- java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68705417) by including lines that are not necessary by other developer to do the same test. `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` was not needed.

```
import os
import sys
os.environ['PYSPARK_PYTHON'] = sys.executable
```

Regarding the environment variables I have `PYSPARK_PYTHON = python`. I have tried also setting the whole pathway to the executable but it does not work.

Any light to understand the behaviour of PySpark or how to avoid the manipulation of files as much as possible, is welcome. The cleanest solution has been to create a symlink as suggested by Martin in [Python or Python3. What is the difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801225).

The full error is:

```
self = <tests.MYENTRYPOINT.MYTEST.MYMAINTEST testMethod=test_run>

    def test_run(self):
        self.to_standard.src_files = file
>       self.to_standard.run()

MY\PATH\TO-DATALAKE.py:44: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
..\MY\PATH\TO-DATALAKE.py:50: in run
    if not df_enriched.rdd.isEmpty():
..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:2920: in isEmpty
    return self.getNumPartitions() == 0 or len(self.take(1)) == 0
..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\rdd.py:2855: in take
    res = self.context.runJob(self, takeUpToNumLeft, p)
..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:2510: in runJob
    sock_info = self._jvm.PythonRDD.runJob(self._jsc.sc(), mappedRDD._jrdd, partitions)
..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1322: in __call__
    return_value = get_return_value(
..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\pyspark\errors\exceptions\captured.py:179: in deco
    return f(*a, **kw)
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 

answer = 'xro116', gateway_client = <py4j.clientserver.JavaClient object at 0x0000024ACB231D50>, target_id = 'z:org.apache.spark.api.python.Py

    def get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id=None, name=None):
        """Converts an answer received from the Java gateway into a Python object.

        For example, string representation of integers are converted to Python
        integer, string representation of objects are converted to JavaObject
        instances, etc.

        :param answer: the string returned by the Java gateway
        :param gateway_client: the gateway client used to communicate with the Java
            Gateway. Only necessary if the answer is a reference (e.g., object,
            list, map)
        :param target_id: the name of the object from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *object1* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        :param name: the name of the member from which the answer comes from
            (e.g., *hello* in `object1.hello()`). Optional.
        """
        if is_error(answer)[0]:
            if len(answer) > 1:
                type = answer[1]
                value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
                if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
>                   raise Py4JJavaError(
                        "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
                        format(target_id, ".", name), value)
E                   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
E                   : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failu
(10.31.2.62 executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specif
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:181)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
E                       at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
E                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
E                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
E                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
E                       ... 19 more
E
E                   Driver stacktrace:
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2844)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2780)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
E                       at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2779)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
E                       at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:1242)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:3048)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2982)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2971)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:984)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2398)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2419)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2438)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD$.runJob(PythonRDD.scala:181)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob(PythonRDD.scala)
E                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
E                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
E                       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
E                       at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
E                       at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
E                       at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
E                       at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
E                       at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
E                       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
E                       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
E                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file speci
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:181)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
E                       at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
E                       at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
E                       at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
E                       at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
E                       at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
E                       at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
E                       at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
E                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
E                       at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
E                       ... 1 more
E                   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
E                       at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
E                       ... 19 more

..\..\..\..\..\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326: Py4JJavaError
------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr call -----------------------------------------
24/02/07 15:36:57 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 2)
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python3": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 19 more
24/02/07 15:36:57 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 2) (10.31.2.62 executor driver): java.io.IOException: Cannot run progra system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1143)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.createSimpleWorker(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonWorkerFactory.create(PythonWorkerFactory.scala:109)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.createPythonWorker(SparkEnv.scala:124)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.BasePythonRunner.compute(PythonRunner.scala:174)
        at org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.compute(PythonRDD.scala:67)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:364)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:93)
        at org.apache.spark.TaskContext.runTaskWithListeners(TaskContext.scala:161)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:141)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$4(Executor.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally(SparkErrorUtils.scala:64)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkErrorUtils.tryWithSafeFinally$(SparkErrorUtils.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:94)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:623)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:499)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
        at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1110)
        ... 19 more

24/02/07 15:36:57 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stderr teardown ---------------------------------------
24/02/07 15:36:58 WARN SparkEnv: Exception while deleting Spark temp dir: C:\MY\PATH\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-ee9599c7-c50c-4ba9-b2-417d-9f1b-fb52b6285c6a
java.io.IOException: Failed to delete: C:\MY\PATH\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-ee9599c7-c50c-4ba9-bf7e-280fde8b1362\userFiles-48d428afantlr4-runtime-4.9.3.jar
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursivelyUsingJavaIO(JavaUtils.java:146)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(JavaUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursivelyUsingJavaIO(JavaUtils.java:129)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(JavaUtils.java:117)
        at org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.deleteRecursively(JavaUtils.java:90)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkFileUtils.deleteRecursively(SparkFileUtils.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.util.SparkFileUtils.deleteRecursively$(SparkFileUtils.scala:120)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.deleteRecursively(Utils.scala:1126)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv.stop(SparkEnv.scala:108)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.$anonfun$stop$25(SparkContext.scala:2310)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1375)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.stop(SparkContext.scala:2310)
        at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.stop(JavaSparkContext.scala:550)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
        at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)
============================================================================= short test summary info ========================================
org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.runJob.
=========================================================================== 1 failed, 1 passed in 13.57s =====================================
PS C:\MY\PATH\tests> SUCCESS: The prID 38068) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 38068 (child process of PID 42040) has been terminated.
SUCCESS: The process with PID 42040 (child process of PID 32248) has been terminated.
```