# Why different versions of Python are installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

I want to clarify that I recently formatted my MacBook and decided to install Python 3.12 from python.org. Command Line Tools was automatically installed. After installing the pkg file I decided to check the version and now I'm confused as to why this is the case.

Why do I have two versions of Python and have to write differently, why do different associations appear

```
vadim@MacBook ~ % python --version
Python 3.9.6
vadim@MacBook ~ % python3 --version
Python 3.12.2
```

```
vadim@MacBook ~ % which python
python: aliased to /usr/bin/python3
vadim@MacBook ~ % which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3
```

Where does Python 3.9 come from?

Comment: macos ships with a default python installation which used to be 2.7.x, but is now 3.x since 2 is obsolete.

Comment: If "python" is still associated with version 3.x
why doesn't it automatically start associating with the most recent installed version?

Comment: Because perhaps that isn't what the user always wants, to always have the latest version associated by default. that said, you can change the default python version, as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5846167/how-to-change-default-python-version) and many other posts on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64801225/python-or-python3-what-is-the-difference/70528020#70528020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying kernel of MacOS is Darwin, a close derivative from Unix BSD. And the command line adds very little magic to a standard Bash shell.

That means that there is nothing like *"python" is associated with version 3*. The standard Python version is installed in `/usr/bin` like the other standard commands, and the name of the Python interpreter executable is `python`. The new version has been installed under `/Library/Frameworks/` like any other *external* tool. And the name of its Python interpreter executable happens to be `python3`. It should even have another link with the full version, just do `ls -l /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python*` to make sure.

When you type `python` or `python3`, the shell searches the PATH for an executable file *having exactly that name* and uses it.

What can be done? If you can stand the current way, do not change it, because it is the standard way. Some tools may expect to find the standard 3.9 version under the name `python`. On the other hand, if you want to have other tools to launch the 3.12 version through the name `python`, you can add a new link to the Python 3 executable:

```
cd /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/
ln -s /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin/python3 python
```

(Use the *real* file name if `python3` is already a symbolic link - I have no Mac on hand to test it...)

But I would not advise you to do that, because it changes what is called under the name `python` for every command using the `PATH`. The blessed way is instead to use *venv*(<sup>*</sup>) to setup a new virtual environment in which `python` and `pip` would call the expected installation, *without disturbing any other installation including the standard one*. More or less:

```
cd my_working_folder
python3.12 -m venv venv
./venv/bin/activate
```

From that point, but only in the current session, `python` will start the 3.12 version.

---

(*) more on the standard Python [doc](https://docs.python.org/fr/3/library/venv.html)

Answer (score 0):

macOS comes with Python already pre-installed.
If you want to use a specific version, you could install Python manually or with a package manager.

Very often, you can use it like

```
python3 --version
```

or with specific versions like

```
python3.12 --version
```

However, this depends mostly on how your PATH and aliases are structured.

Installing Python versions directly is a bit harder, so you could use a tool like Homebrew to install multiple versions. Also, a virtual environment could help develop using different Python versions.

https://brew.sh/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Edit: based on the comment made by triplee, I restructured the answer to clarify that I intended to provide alternatives to overcomplicate the process for someone new to Python development, and my intention wasn't to enforce anything.

Comment: Whether "your own version" provides a command named `python3` or `python3.12` very much depends on how exactly you installed it and where you got it from, and how you subsequently configured your `PATH`. I feel this answer is too hand-wavy to be useful.

Comment: @tripleee I restructured it a bit. As I mentioned in my answer, I want to provide an easy solution and not enforce anything. The tools I referenced have been useful to me in the past, and it could be useful for others. Thanks for your feedback.